# Regular Expression help to match below code

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression to fetch any URL between double quotes.

```
<a href="http://www.any-web_address.com">
<a href="http://142.12.64.71:8083">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://[0-9 a-z A-Z . : ]{1,100}"
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.  In particular, I don't see how this matches URLs such as `ftp://server/file` or `mailto:user@host`...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
\"\K([\w\:\/\.\-]+)
```

If You want with double quotes (it was said "fetch any url between double quotes" so I thought without \"):

```
\"([\w\:\/\.\-]+)\"
```

Comment: Side question: Why the `\K` if you match with a group anyway? Just curious.

Comment: It was said "fetch any url BETWEEN double quotes" so in my understanding - without them.
So find first \", clear position  - \K and then rest of regex - match url.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion (in case your regex flavour supports lookarounds):

```
(?<=href="|link="|src=")(((http|https)(:\/\/))?([\/\w\-]{2,})(([\.])([\w\-]*)){1,})([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-]*)(?=")
```

Comment: suppose I have something like this in code <td sorttable_customkey="14905.0">, It will select that too

Comment: I've made an edit on the regex. Now it will only match after `href="` or `link="`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not reduce the scope of your problem, this post : [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la) may help you. Else, for instance if you only want the URIs after `href=`, you can do this like that :

```
/(?:href=")(.[^"]*)"/g
```

Comment: it will include keyword href=" also  P.S:- I'm new to regex so might be wrong.

Comment: (?:blablabla...) is a non-capturing group (because of ?:), whereas (blablabla...) is a capturing one, so no it won't. You can test your regex here : https://regex101.com/#javascript it explains pretty well.

Comment: http(.[^"]*) this will also help

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this will not capture http then.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

`.*href="(\S*)"` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS7sW1/2)

We are effectively looking for the presence of `href=` and then capturing all non-whitespace characters that appear between double quotes.